# How to bring team's changes into my branch as neatly as possible?

Tags: git

I've been puzzling over this and can't figure out an answer. Let's say my team is working on `origin/develop` (which I'm tracking locally) and I'm working on a local branch `feat-search`. I'm several commits in, and want to bring in any changes from `develop` into my branch. My options are:

1. `git pull origin develop`
2. `git pull --rebase origin develop`
3. `git checkout develop; git pull origin develop; git checkout feat-search; git rebase develop`
4. `git checkout develop; git pull origin develop; git checkout feat-search; git merge develop`
5. none of the above; just keep working on my branch and don't bring in changes from `develop`

The thing is, I think if I use `git pull --rebase`, the git graph is collapsed when I merge my branch in and it looks visually like I never branched off. People may not like that. If I use `git pull`, it merges develop into my branch which looks strange on a graph as well.

I'm confused as hell. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: git fetch origin; git merge origin/develop

Comment: Several articles I've read say otherwise. When pulling changes into a branch (downstream), use `rebase`, and use `merge` to merge upstream.

Comment: This is a normal case.. usually rebase is a good answer. If you (personally) want to save your history, then use a merge. THe bigger question is what to do when a feature branch is shared among several people...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `git pull --rebase`, the git graph is collapsed when I merge my branch in and it looks visually like I never branched off.

That is not a bug, that is a feature, which keep the history linear.
But that doesn't remove the branch: you are still branching off `origin/develop`. You simply make sure the merge back to `develop` will be a trivial one (because you are working from the latest commits of `origin/develop`).

One could even [advocate to make sure a git pull always rebase](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2013/02/merge-vs-rebase/):

```
git config --global --bool pull.rebase true
```

If you have many local feature branches to rebase, you even can automate the process [with `git-rebranch`](https://github.com/dankeder/git-rebranch).